# Cutting out custom shapes in Affinity Designer behaves oddly

Tags: layers, affinity-designer

Something weird happens when I try to subtract a Curves layer from a Curve layer.

[image: Start]

[image: Subtracted]

What should I do to cut out the guy from the rectangle?

Comment: The case is a puzzle. Can you reveal how the guy shape is constructed and show it with no fill, but with a thin stroke? Or the nodes view? is it a SVG or other import?

Comment: Bingo: https://i.imgur.com/2TYVWuZ.png I glued the guy together by combining basic shapes. Guess something went wrong while merging his right arm. Thanks user287001!